# Can't connect to Amazon Athena from Power BI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, powerbi, amazon-athena

ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Athena] (1040) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. Error Message: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: C5Z10AA7AE81NKH0; S3 Extended Request ID: PRYTg/7fb1/0PL8vtHy1Z5UoxDUIgVpMmUbj1SO3xN3NoUNQ10oOY78bi8Y57iQ7ouN6Ifg/TsTfX5zsM4M/9g==; Proxy: null) [Execution ID: f8d91a56-1c84-4f8e-9981-87e228374e2f]

Thats the error it shows me, I already configured my IAM Policy to access to my S3 Bucket.

Comment: The role used from powerBI has access to athena? Does it have access to the source bucket? Is it encrypted using kms? Does it have a bucket policy? Does your role has access to destination bucket? Is it encrypted using kms? Does it have a bucket policy?